# How to convert base64 into NSDATA in swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, avfoundation

I am working on an iOS project. It stores audio on web server in the form of base64 string. When I request server to get base64 Strings for all audios and tried convert it in `NSData` I am getting `nil`.

```
do
{
   var audioData: NSData! = NSData(base64EncodedString: audioBase64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue:0))
   if audioData != nil
   {
      let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData)
      sound.play()
   }
   else
   {
        print("Data Not Exist")
   }
}
catch
{
}
```

On Android same base64 string is converted into byte array and is playing, but in iOS `audioBase64String` return `nil` for `NSData`.

Comment: Include a sample base64 in your question. Is it possible that adding `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters` already fixes the issue? (maybe you b64 ends in a newline?)

Comment: You already getting Base 64 String from server and you again doing same thing for encoding thats why you not getting result. So need to do decode now.

Comment: thanks @hnh 
Solved

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works:

**Swift 3 and 4:**

```
var audioData = Data(base64Encoded: recording_base64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```

**Swift 2:**

```
var audioData = NSData(base64EncodedString: recording_base64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3:

```
var audioData = Data(base64Encoded: recording_base64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [this library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64). You can get NSData from base64 string and then init your AVAudioPlayer with this data. Please read [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithData:error:)  Apple's Documentation.