# data from base64 url

Tags: swift, url

I have a URL in the form of

`foo://?data:application/x-foo;base64,OjAyMDAwMDA0MDAwMEZBDQo6MTAwMDA...`

and now need to extract the base64 data into a `Data` object.

Unfortunately it seems the `Data` object does not support this yet as

`let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)`

returns `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002` when trying.

While I could [decode the URL manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206139/how-to-convert-base64-into-nsdata-in-swift) I am wondering if I am missing a simple standard way of doing this. How would you do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert base64 into NSDATA in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206139/how-to-convert-base64-into-nsdata-in-swift)

Comment: Not really as that is just about base64 conversion, @the4kman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you *can* decode Base64 data from an URL (see for 
example [Base64 Decoding in iOS 7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7/22432808#22432808) where this is demonstrated in Objective-C). The format is a bit different from what 
you have:

```
let url = URL(string: "data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!) // Hello world!
```

(Error checking omitted for brevity.)

Comment: I knew this should be working. Great catch, Martin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the base64 encoded part of the URL from the other parts, decode it, then join the original non-encoded part with the decoded part and get the data from there.

```
extension URL {
    init?(partialBase64Url: String){
        guard let base64part = base64Url.components(separatedBy: "base64,").last, let base64Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64part), let decodedString = String(data: base64Data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        let decodedUrl = base64Url.components(separatedBy: "base64,").dropLast().joined() + decodedString
        self.init(string: decodedUrl)
    }
}

let decodedUrl = URL(partialBase64Url: "foo://?data:application/x-foo;base64,dGVzdFVybFN0cmluZw==")
```

Value of `decodedUrl`: `"foo://?data:application/x-foo;testUrlString"`, as expected, since `dGVzdFVybFN0cmluZw==` is the base64 encoded value of `testUrlString`.

Comment: So essentially you are saying there is no easier way but doing this manually. (Thanks for the example)

Comment: AFAIK there's not automatic method for downloading data from a partially encoded URL, so yes, you have to do it manually.

Comment: @tcurdt check my updated answer, I created a failable initializer for URL using the decoding function, this might be more convenient for you.

Comment: While your code does work fine, too it really is the manual solution. Martin's answer provides the automatic method. Thanks anyway!