# Swift base 64 string DIRECTLY to Jpeg on filesystem

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am getting base64 images in an API call and I need to store these as files locally.

I was trying to write this data **without** having to **convert** the string **to UIImage** and **then** UIImage to **JPEGRepresentation**.

I don't want the overhead of creating UIImages first and theen changing to JPEGs if I can avoid it, but I don't know if this is possible?

I can see in my app Container, that all the files are there and the correct filesize but when I try to open them, they won't and I am told they may be corrupt.

```
extension NSData {

    func writeToURL2(named:URL, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool, _ url:NSURL?) -> Void)  {

        let tmpURL = named as NSURL

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] () -> Void in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { completion (false, tmpURL); return }

            strongSelf.write(to: tmpURL as URL, atomically: true)
            var error:NSError?
            if tmpURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) {
                print("We have it")
                completion(true, tmpURL)
            } else {
                print("We Don't have it\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                completion (false, tmpURL)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

and it is used like:

```
for employee in syncReponse
            {
                autoreleasepool{
                    if let employeeJsonStr = employee["data"] as? String{


                        if let employeeDataDict = try? JSONSerializer.toDictionary(employeeJsonStr), let proPic = employeeDataDict["profilepicture"] as? String, proPic.removingWhitespaces() != "", let idStr = employeeDataDict["employeeId"] as? String, let proPicData = (proPic.data(using: .utf8)) {

                            let empPicDir = mainDir.appendingPathComponent(util_Constants.DIR_EMP_PICS)
                            let filename = empPicDir.appendingPathComponent(idStr+".jpg")

                            (proPicData as NSData).writeToURL2(named: filename, completion: { (result, url) -> Void in

                            })
                        }

                        let Emp = DATA_EP_employee(employeeJsonStr : employeeJsonStr)
                        dataList.append(Emp)
                        reqCount += 1
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: So you want `Encoded64String` to `Data` and write that `Data` into your target path.  Then just use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206139/how-to-convert-base64-into-nsdata-in-swift?

Comment: @Larme, yes sorry that was ridiculously easy!! -_- I didn't think of creating the data using: Data(base64Encoded: proPic, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)

Comment: Note, you seem to use Swift3+, avoid NSStuff when possible, so `URL` instead of `NSURL`, `Data` over `NSData`, etc.

Comment: @Larme perfect will do